# Why this.$listeners is undefined in Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js

**Vue.js version:** 2.4.2

Below component always print `this.$listeners` as `undefined`.

```
module.exports = {
    template: `<h1>My Component</h1>`,
    mounted() {
        alert(this.$listeners);
    }
}
```

I register the component and put it inside a parent component.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Does this alert an object when you try it in the parent component? Also note that $listeners need Vue 2.4+.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what `$listeners` are.

`this.$listeners` will be populated once there are components that listen to events that your components is emitting.

let's assume 2 components:

**child.vue**  - emits an event each time something is written to input field.

```
<template>
    <input @input="emitEvent">
    </input>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    emitEvent() {
      this.$emit('important-event')
      console.log(this.$listeners)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**parent.vue** - listen to the events from `child` component.

```
<template>
  <div class="foo">
    <child @important-event="doSomething"></child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from './child.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newcomment: {
        post_id: 'this is default value'
      }
    }
  },
  components: { child },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

With this setup, when you type something to the input field, this object should be written to the console:

```
{
    `important-event`: function () { // some native vue.js code} 
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why $listeners is undefined (since it should be an empty object before it is populated). Example of expected behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/71456/ Because of this I think the OP might be using an older Vue version that doesn't support $listeners or something else could be responsible for this unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Wouter I am using Vue 2.4.2.

Comment: what do u get when you print only `this`?

Answer (score -2):

I added the following alias to my webpack.config.js file and this resolved the issue for me:-

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'vue$': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js')
        }
    },
```